# Detect Click on a Child Control Hidden by Other Overlapped Child Control

Tags: winforms

I need a clever algorithm to detect which edge was clicked, while not looking into every edge in the graph.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the areas marked by dots show clicked edge incorrectly because they're overlapped by edge [2->3]

I tried GetChildAtPoint but it returns only the topmost child.

```
    class Edge : Control {
       public Movable From {get;set;}
       public Movable To {get;set;}
    ...}

    void Edge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var clicked = (Edge)sender;
        var mpc = this.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        var clk0 = this.GetChildAtPoint(mpc) as Edge;
        Edge clk = null;
        if (clk0 != null) {
            if (clk0.GetType() == typeof(Edge))
                clk = clk0 as Edge;                 
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("({0}, {1}): {2} - {3}=>{4} - {5}: {6}",
            mpc.X, mpc.Y, clicked.Parent.GetType().ToString(),
            clicked.From.Text, clicked.To.Text,
            (clicked == clk).ToString(),
            clk == null ? "null" : clk.From.Text + "=>" + clk.To.Text));
    }
```

How could I iterate over all child windows/controls under some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to iterate through your Form's Control Collection and check if the Bounds of each control contains your point.

This may or may not be feasible for you depending on the number of Controls that you have.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls )
{
    if (c.Bounds.Contains(mpc))
    {
        //process the match here
    }
}
```